# Why the index of a v-for used as a method parameter in another component doesn't equal to the initial index value?

Tags: vuejs2, modal-dialog, vue-component, v-for

My problem is the following one: I have a list of bank accounts, they are looped in a v-for. For each bank account, I have a button to be able to delete it. When a user delete a bank account, I want to display a confirmation modal with a confirm method. I have to pass the index of the v-for to the method to know which element I have to delete from the original array. When I passed that index, it doesn't match to the index of the current element.
Here is a visual support:

```
<div v-for="(bankAccount, index) in bankAccounts" :key="bankAccount.id">
  <ModalConfirm @close="showModal = false" @confirmDelete="deleteBA(index)" v-if="showModal" />

  <div>
    <section>
      <p class="color--lg light">{{ bankAccount.name }}</p>
    </section>

    <section>
      <button @click="showModal = true">
        Delete bank account
      </button>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

So here, the index value in the method **deleteBA** is not the same than the original index of the v-for. I can't understand why !

I created a live example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/6jo79vr1lk

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is in the following code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello card-container">
    <ul v-for="(element, index) in elements" :key="index">
      <li class="card">
        <div>{{ index }}</div>
        <div>
          <button @click="showModal = true;">Delete bank account {{element}}</button>
        </div>
        <ModalConfirm
          @close="showModal = false;"
          @confirmDelete="deleteBA(index);"
          v-if="showModal"
        />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

you have one modal for each account , but use a single boolean value to toggle all. `@click="showModal = true;"`

While there are ways to handle that by adding a modal boolean for each item, it's unnecessary to have a modal for each item, and better to reuse the same modal.

you can use a modal index instead of a boolean, so `@click="showModal = index"`

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello card-container">
    <ul v-for="(element, index) in elements" :key="index">
      <li class="card">
        <div>{{ index }}</div>
        <div>
          <button @click="showModal = index;">Delete bank account {{element}}</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ModalConfirm
      @close="showModal = -1"
      @confirmDelete="deleteBA(showModal);"
      v-if="showModal >= 0"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: Wow, big thanks ! I couldn't get a better answer than that.